# How do I perform sequential BringIntoView calls in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

We have a `TreeView` in our application with the following requirements:

When an item is added:

1. The newly-added item is scrolled into view
2. The parent of the newly added item is also scrolled into view.
3. If they are too far away to both be seen at the same time, the item takes precedence.

This seems easy, simply scroll the parent into view first, then scroll the child.

The problem is when you call it like this:

```
parent.BringIntoView();
child.BringIntoView();
```

...only the second one seems to have any effect.  The first one is basically ignored.

I then tried wrapping the second call in a `BeginInvoke()` call like this:

```
parent.BringIntoView();

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    child.BringIntoView();
}));
```

Which does work, but now you can visibly see the `TreeView` scroll twice; once for the parent, then a moment later, for the child, which just looks bad.

So how can I call `BringIntoView` back-to-back but without the double-refresh issue of using the dispatcher?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Loaded` event instead of the dispatcher. According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx), it's a perfect fit for situations like this:

> ... we initially implemented the Loaded event so that
>   it would fire just after the window was rendered, but before any input
>   was processed.  We figured that if it was ready enough for input, it
>   was ready enough for load-time initialization.  But then we started to
>   trigger animations off of the Loaded event, and saw the problem; for a
>   split second you’d see the content render without the animation, then
>   you’d see the animation start.  You might not always notice it, but it
>   was especially noticeable when you run the app remotely.
>
> So we moved
>   Loaded so that it now fires after layout and data binding have had a
>   chance to run, but just before the first render.  (And note that if
>   you do anything in your Loaded event handler that invalidates layout,
>   it might be necessary to re-run it before rendering.)

In other words, on Loaded you have the most up to date information about the physical layout of the element, but it hasn't actually rendered yet, so you should be safe from any "screen flicker" issues.

**EDIT**: To answer your question in the comments, you can wire up events "local" to the current method using a closure, like this:

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, e) => {
    this.LayoutUpdated -= handler;  // only run once
    child.BringIntoView();
};
this.LayoutUpdated += handler;
```

By defining the handler inside the method, you are able to access the method's local variables (`child`) from within. Very similar to the `Dispatcher` call.

I'm not sure if relying on `LayoutUpdated` is a good idea, actually. It happens quite often so it may end up firing sooner than you need. It happens twice for individual `Width` and `Height` settings, for example. Another one to look into is [ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx). Or you could avoid `BringIntoView` altogether and try manually examining the element sizes to calculate where to scroll to.

Comment: The code I tried is actually *in* the loaded event for the node, but thats not the issue.  Again, the issue is back-to-back BringIntoView calls where the first one is basically usurped by the second and rendered ineffective.

Comment: Still, I believe your solution of delaying the second call makes sense. The issue is that it's being delayed too long, and it happens after render (causing the double-refresh to be visible). If Loaded has already happened, try [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx).

Comment: But that is its own event.  Remember... this action is triggered by the user.  Can you show me how would you wire this up so you can respond to the user, then respond to a system event as part of the same transaction.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a separate event -- just don't wire up the handler anywhere else other than the response to the user, and make sure that handler only runs once, so it effectively happens only as a direct result of the user action. See my edit to the answer for more.